# Web fonts in html emails with Gmail

Tags: html, gmail, google-webfonts

Given Google's support for some style tags in Gmail emails:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

but not for @font-face, I am curious as to why @font-face is not supported? What is the technical reason?

Are there security concerns?